# How to host azure SharePoint 2016 site to external network?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, azure

I have created document center on azure SharePoint 2016 server. now I want to make it accessible thru outside of the network.But currently, I am able to access within the network only.
To make it accessible thru outside network what I tried so far:

- Created SP site on Azure
- Extended the web application on 9090 port (site port)
  (HTTP) and secure port 443 (https)
- Registered the DNS name/end points
  on Azure
- I also installed TLS 1.0, TLS
  1.1, SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0 protocols on SharePoint 2016 server.

Still no luck! Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have provisioned a VM in Microsoft Azure. After you have configured web application(s), you need to configure NSG rules in Azure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using Virtual machines (Classic) mode, where I can't find networking tab to set rules, I configured End Points though.